# Does Linear Programming always require equality (e.g. >=0) in the solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

In linear programming system we encounter
problem statement as below

$maximize\ c^T \\
subject\ to \ Ax \leq b\\
and\ x \ge 0
$

My question is that is it possible to set the solution to be strictly greater than zero

$x > 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you demand $x>0$ instead of $x\geq 0$, the maximum may not exist. For example:

> Maximize $-x$ subject to $1\cdot x \leq 1$ and $x>0$

is not solvable. The set of values that you are maximizing is $(-1,0)$, and this set has no maximum element. It has a supremum, $0$, but the supremum is not attained for any $x$.

Comment: Does it also hold for 'minimization'. For example NNLS (non-negative least square)?

Comment: @neversaint I don't know about NNLS, but I am 99% sure that the answer is yes. You need *closed* sets if you want to actually have values that reach the maximum.

Comment: How about $x >= 0.000001$ some small value. It will give a solution right? Can we say it's equivalent to $x>0$ ?

Comment: @neversaint Most certainly not. The maximum of $-x$ subject to $x>0$ **does not exist**. The **supremum** of $-x$ is equal to $0$. On the other hand, the maximum of $-x$ subject to $x\geq 0.000001$ exists, and is equal to $-0.000001$ which is also the supremum. Conceptually, these are two completely different things. Calling them equivalent would be a huge mistake.